# Does Facebook provide an SSL/TLS interface?

Tags: facebook, security, ssl, https

Does Facebook only support HTTP or does it have HTTPS also?

Comment: Check this http://facecrooks.com/blog/internet-safety-a-privacy/item/1026-secure-your-facebook-account-with-https-in-three-steps

Comment: Yes [https://www.facebook.com/](https://www.facebook.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As of July 2013](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/secure-browsing-by-default/10151590414803920), Facebook is https by default:

> We now use https by default for all Facebook users. This feature, which we first introduced as an option two years ago, means that your browser is told to communicate with Facebook using a secure connection, as indicated by the "https" rather than "http" in [the URL]

However, the http interface remains

> Some mobile phones and mobile carrier gateways don't fully support https. While we're working with the vendors of these products, we didn't want to leave https off entirely for affected users.

This is regrettable because it leaves possible the [sslstrip attack](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) whereby a man-in-the-middle rewrites https links to http, and serves a similar looking page at the http url. The solution is the [HSTS header](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/07/19/hope9talk.html) which tells the browser to *always* use https for a given site.

Answer (score 10):

Yes - have a look at https://ssl.facebook.com/, however I do not think it is intended for use. All links from this site will redirect you back to non-SSL. I suppose it's grand if you want to check your live feed securely.

As a note: Going to https://www.facebook.com will throw a certificate error, so rather use the above link for access.

Comment: Why do they have that weird setup?

Comment: @Micheal - To be honest I've found it quite weird myself and am not sure at all. I don't think it's meant to be used though since all links redirect away from SSL.

Answer (score 10):

**Notice:** This answer is now out of date.

This feature has become publicly available, however it is turned off by default.

To enable it, navigate to `Account Settings` > `Account Security` and check the `HTTPS` box.

Comment: Wow, why isn't this advertised more, or even... on by default... I think this is the correct answer!

Comment: Definitely the right answer.  Thanks!

Comment: More info: https://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=486790652130

Comment: Just note that SSL is not enabled on the login page, which almost defeats the whole point of enabling SSL. Read more here: http://www.digitalsociety.org/2011/02/facebook-https-now-works-but-forgot-ssl-authentication/

Answer (score 6):

https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere

That Firefox add-on will force SSL connections for Facebook, in addition to a growing number of other websites that support SSL (like wikipedia, google, meebo, etc). Future add-on updates will add support for additional sites.