# How to always browse Facebook using HTTPS

Tags: facebook, security, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Facebook provide an SSL interface?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/214/does-facebook-provide-an-ssl-interface)

I've googled and searched on our site here, but the best I can find is the question *[How to get Facebook to use “http://” instead of “https://”](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15399/how-to-get-facebook-to-use-http-instead-of-https)*, though in a reversed meaning to mine.

I want to always browse Facebook with the HTTPS protocol. In Facebook, I see there's a setting related to this—I want a reversed feature, that is, always HTTPS, not HTTP.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use this **https://ssl.facebook.com/** link, it will land on **https://www.facebook.com** but all links from this site will redirect you back to non-SSL.

To enable permanently,

```
Click on Home --> Account Settings --> Account Security and check the HTTPS box.
```

Answer (score 2):

Other than Siva's correct answer via Facebook settings, you can optionally force HTTPS on a variety of sites with an additional browser plugin, [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere).

I do recommend disabling HTTPS Everywhere for Google search services. It tends to have a glitch with the new way Google presents search results without clicking on the search button.